# emails going to wrong case

Tags: email, case

In salesforce the reference # that goes in the subject number alot of the emails are in the wrong case. what is root cause for this emails going to wrong case number with different subject line

Comment: Hi, can you refine your question a little more? In which scenario? when and where?

Comment: when user is responding to mail to salesforce it is addressing wrong case number and subject line also different... for more info if u want screenshot i will send... please let me know,,where i will attach screenshot..

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any email templates created and in use? Maybe the wrong templates are being selected when email is sent. I would check those settings.